# Sample from a distribution inside a NN layer

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

Is it possible to sample from a distribution inside a neural network forward function? Assume that there is a NN and a sample is needed to be derived from it at every forward-pass to randomly set a layer-specific hyper-parameter.

Is this operation differentiable